How to update value in json object with key as argument (using `jq`)
Using jq I want to update a value in a json object.
The key of the value to be updated is passed as an argument.
Input
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3
}

Expected output with argument: key=b
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 42,
  "c": 3
}

I tried to do:
jq --arg key b '.($key) |= . + 40'
jq --arg key b '".\($key)" |= . + 40'

Both attempts result in errors:

syntax error, unexpected '('
Invalid path expression with result ".b"

How can I solve this problem?

A key needs an . in front of it, then since it's in a variable, use [].
jq --arg key b '.[$key] |= (. * 999)' input

Gives:
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 1998,
  "c": 3
}

You can also replace |= . *  with the *= operator:
jq --arg key b '.[$key] *= 999' input


Your first attempt didn't work since you need [] instead off ()
The second one failed because wrapping it in a  string literal will create a string .b, that's not something you can update using |=.
